# How to combine a query in WP

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

How to make a query so that all products are displayed, except for Out of Stock, but if the meta field is "visible", show and the goods with Out of Stock, too?

Thanks

```
function test_function($query) {
    if (!$query->is_main_query() || is_admin()) {
        return;
    }

    if ($outofstock_term = get_term_by('name', 'outofstock', 'product_visibility')) {
        $tax_query = (array) $query->get('tax_query');

        $tax_query[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility',
            'field' => 'term_taxonomy_id',
            'terms' => array($outofstock_term->term_taxonomy_id),
            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
        );

        $query->set('tax_query', $tax_query);
    }


    $meta_query = array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'test_visibility',
            'value'     => 'hidden', 
            'operator'  => 'NOT LIKE'
        )
    );

    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query);
}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'test_function');
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! That first sentences is quite long and horribly complicated. I suggest editing it to improve your chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**How to add meta query and tax query in WP Query?**

```
<?php
$cats_args=array(
    'type'                     => 'products', //posttype name
    'post_status'              => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'           => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'         => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
                        array('key' => 'test_visibility',
                              'value' => 'hidden', 
                              'compare' => '!=',
                        )
                    ),
    'orderby'                  => 'name',                   
    'order'                    => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'hierarchical'             => true,
    'exclude'                  => '',
    'include'                  => '',
    'number'                   => '',
    'tax_query'                => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'product_visibility', //taxonomy name
                                            'field' => 'name',
                                            'terms' => 'outofstock',
                                            'operator' => 'NOT IN'
                                        )
                                    ),
);
$cats_my_query = null;
$cats_my_query = new WP_Query($cats_args);

if( $cats_my_query->have_posts() ) 
{
     $cats_count=0;
     while ($cats_my_query->have_posts()) : $cats_my_query->the_post(); 
       $cats_count++;
        echo $cats_my_query->post_name;
      endwhile;

}
wp_reset_query($cats_my_query);
?>
```

Comment: no, i know how just combine, i need combine with "OR" or something like this...look at the question...